# How to make a div to span below when a href was clicked?

Tags: php, if-statement, href

I want to make an if statement where a  will span after user clicks a href.
The problem is that I don't know how to make the if statement looks like. This is the href

```
echo"<td><a href='catchhistory.php?id=$iddoc'> View Result </a></td>";
```

Comment: I want to make an if statement where a <div> will span after user clicks the href. (Please forgive my bad english)

Comment: You'll need some JavaScript for that. Otherwise you would need to refresh the page after the user clicks. Once the PHP has rendered your HTML the server's job is done - it can not respond to user interactions.

Comment: PHP is only for server side scripting. That you can't use for click event. You need to apply client side scripting like javascript,jquery etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it easier to make it on jQuery javascript

```
 $(function () { 
    var my_div = $('#myDiv');
    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
     $(this).after(my_div).show();

    }
}
```

add ID to your

`<div id='myDiv' style='display:none'>tqweqwe</div>`

add ID to your href

`<a id='myButton' href="#">qeqwe</a>`

Comment: I also want to make a <div> to appear below after I clicked a submit button. The appeared <div> then contains another two buttons (table and histogram button) which will span another <div> to show table and histogram one-by-one.

Comment: I already can make all the <div> to span. Now my problem is that when I put them in another <div>, the span does not happen.

Comment: why when I clicked the href, it doesn't span myDiv?

Comment: Coz, there's it only hidden at start, if you want to dublicate them, then you should make 
`var html = $('#myDiv');
 html = html.clone();
 html.after('#someTarget');`